# How to test a function which has a call to get connection to db within it using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have to test a function which has a call within it to get the snowflake connection object. I have created a fixture with dummy data for the main Class itself which has the function to test as well as the function to get connection which is used within the "to be tested" function.

This is the sample structure to visualize :

```
class SnowFlakeHelperClass:
    ...
    def _get_snowflake_connection() -> SnowflakeConnection:
       ...
    def to_be_tested_function():
       conn = self._get_snowflake_connection()
```

I have created fixture to replicate `SnowFlakeHelperClass`. and Im testing like below

```
def test_my_function(fixture_for_class):
   assert fixture_for_class.to_be_tested_function() = something
```

But because I have a connection call within the function, this is not working.

Comment: The standard way to handle this in a unit test is to mock the database client or something else in the chain to making a real connection depending on how deep you want to test.

Comment: @possum It would be really helpful if you have a code example. My target is actually to test an exception down the line. This connection is just on the way. So I somehow wanna skip it

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to be given an example that would be more useful than looking for mocking libraries on your own.